# Unity3D Objects Positioning

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, gameobject

It is my first Unity project so the question might be silly.
I Have created two 3d object with blender and imported the fbx (Autodesk) file in a Unity3D project. The problem is that when I instantiate the assets in the editor, the objects are always rendered at the same position (the one they had in blender) though I have actually changed it (in Unity).

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you Instantiating the assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly this is caused by fbx exporter. If objects don't have animations, uncheck animation box in fbx exporter.

If you instantiate objects by script you probably set wrong position of objects. It should look something like this:

```
var Object:GameObject; //This object should be assigned from project pan.
var pos:Vector3; //Wanted object position in world
var rot=Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0); //Wanted object rotation(all zeros sets it to original)
//This should be in some function
var name = Instantiate(Object, pos, rot);
```